# Show image change URL without reload the page

Tags: javascript, php

How can I click an image, open the image without reloading with php and javascript?

```
<?php
    echo '<li>
      <a href="photo.php?id='.$id.'">
      <div class="_th_alb">
        <img src="image/'.$allbum_photos.'" >
      </div></a>
    </li>';
?>
```

[with like image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmtaO.jpg)

Comment: use some plugin !

Comment: check the answer posted by @Splinti.

Comment: i know make it but need change url and show each image when clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a modal.

You can see some examples right here:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

To the modifying URL part:

You can use

`window.history.pushState('a string or object', 'Title', '?image=as1234da3sdasd');`

Hope this helps

Comment: with like post photo facebook and vk ... etc

Comment: Um, sorry? The examples shown on that page, are written with javascript, there's no need to change the url or forward to any other site. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: sorry :( , Splinti see the
[link](https://postimg.org/image/5wwa9e4cd/) when u click image open and change url